# "incorect command line error" when compressing file via subprocess

Tags: python, windows, 7zip

I need to compress a batch of files via subprocess and 7z.exe. Their names start with "-".
It seems that 7z cannot accept that. There is no problem with other files starting with "+".

Is there a workaround?

thank you!

```
import os
import subprocess


subprocess.call(['7z.exe', 'a', '-01+005_compressed.txt', '-01+005_orig.txt', '-mx9'], shell=True)
```

Error:

Incorrect command line

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Add a `--` in front of the filenames, to prevent recognition of subsequent arguments as flags:

```
subprocess.call(['7z.exe', 'a', '--', '-01+005_compressed.txt', '-01+005_orig.txt', '-mx9'], shell=True)
```